# Erase string from the screen drawn by drawAtPoint

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I just want to ask how to erase an string from the screen that is drawn by -drawAtPoint method of NSString.

Some details are below:

Draw Function

```
  void  DrawString (NSString * str)
  {
      [str drawAtPoint: NSMakePoint(x,y) withAttributes: MyAttributes];
  }
```

Clear function

```
 void EraseString (NSString * str)
 {
       //Code to delete str from the screen.
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't "erase" what you draw. You simply do not draw it the next time that `drawRect:` is called. For example, when you set the state of the string in your view, call `setNeedsDisplay:` For example:

```
-(void)setShowString:(BOOL)showString
{
    _showString = showString;
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

Then in your `drawRect:` method, you check the state:

```
if ([self showString])
    [str drawAtPoint: NSMakePoint(x,y) withAttributes: MyAttributes];
```

The string will show or hide the string when you call setShowString:

Alternatively, you could set the string value (assuming non-ARC project):

```
-(void)setStr:(NSString*)newString
{
    [newString retain];
    [_str release];
    _str = newString;

    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

And check the string in your `drawRect:`:

```
if ([[self str] length] > 0)
    [_str drawAtPoint: NSMakePoint(x,y) withAttributes: MyAttributes];
```

Comment: In my case, I am maintaining an array of strings to be displayed. I just removed them from the string and use your method.